# Can't install gcc cross compiler

Tags: software-installation, apt, kali-linux

I try to cross compile Bluez. Therefor i need to install "libical" which is a prerequisite of BlueZ. I am following [this guide](http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_BlueZ_Bluetooth_tools_for_ARM).

From the guide:

> libical requires cmake and g++ cross compilers to be installed:
>
> sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabi

But if I execute `sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabi`
I get:

> Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
>   Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig E: Paket
>   g++-arm-linux-gnueabi kann nicht gefunden werden. E: Mittels regulärem
>   Ausdruck »g++-arm-linux-gnueabi« konnte kein Paket gefunden werden.

Which is german and means "Package not found." I also did `sudo apt-get update` before.

**OS Info**

```
$ uname -m Output: x86_64

$ cat /etc/issue Output: Kali GNU/Linux 1.1.0 \n \l
```

Comment: Do you want to install `BlueZ` on `ARM` or `x86` machine?

Comment: I need to cross compile it for `ARM`

Comment: You said: `I try to install Bluez` - so do you want install it or compile it? You have to be more clear.

Comment: I want to cross compile it. Sorry, i changed the description.

Answer (score 3):

`g++-arm-linux-gnueabi` package is provided by [`gcc-defaults-armel-cross`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults-armel-cross) in Ubuntu 12.04+ or [`cross-gcc-defaults`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/cross-gcc-defaults) in Debian unstable (sid) .  It's unavailable in Debian stable releases or derived distributions based on them.

Follow [the instruction in Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossToolchains#Installation) to install various cross toolchains on Debian stable releases.

Comment: I will try it on Ubuntu 15.04 as soon as possible. I will report any updates here.